# using a key value other than Schema.Types.ObjectId in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I am creating a collection w/n mongo using mongoose to populate related users.  I have clinicians and patients.  I want patients to have an array of clinicians as they are enrolledwith.  Later I'll load a dashboard for clincian based on patient user "enrolledWith: "

Likely clincians will provide their email to patients to be marked in rolled.  emails are username.

**Can I use username for the Schema.Types.username?**

```
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  phoneNumber: String,
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  patient: {
    // role: Boolean,
    enrolledWith: [
      {
        type: mongoose.Schema.username,
        ref: 'User'
      }
    ],
    gameTotalScore: Number,
  },
  // clinician: {
  //   role: Boolean
  // },
  role: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

});
```

Comment: Why do you need to use username as a reference? What is the problem with _id created by mongo?

Comment: the thinking was that when a patient signs up they'll know their therapist's email address and not their therapist mongo _id.    My solution was instead to not reference schema relationship between therapist and client. Instead, I put the username (email address) as a string and looped it to forEach(), generating a list of clients in a therapist's dashboard who had in their enrolled with array that therapist's username

Comment: Have you solved the problem?